# Email Issue in Magento 2

Tags: email, magento2.2.0, newsletter-subscriber

Email is not received after subscribe but I got a success message in the home page. How to fix it?

Comment: have you posted anything new in your site?

Comment: Are you getting other emails from the website, i.e. customer account creation, forgot password, etc.?

Comment: No, i didn't get anyother emails

Answer (score 1):

> Newsletters are for easily inform customers about new products,
>   specials, promos, etc.

Please read here [Newsletter Functionality](https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/cat/magento-2-email-newsletter/)

Also check How to configure [Configuring Newsletters](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/newsletter-configuration.html)

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: i do this still not working am using in localhost

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `SMTP` extension to send emails in local environment

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

And You can see the details for the configuration [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-configure-mailcom-smtp-in-magento-2.html)